# Tidyverse solution for overlapping start/end 'days from index'

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have start dates and end dates ('days from index') and want to change the end date if it is <=50 days to the next start date within each group, i.e. 'bridge' the time periods.

Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(effective_time_from_index_start = c(373, 569, 932, 1280, 1410, 1610, 20, 80, NA, 140),
                     effective_time_from_index_end = c(520,  883, 1233, 1387, 1624, NA, 40, 100, 120, NA),
                     group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)),
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    effective_time_from_index_start effective_time_from_index_end group
#>                              <dbl>                         <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1                             373                           520     1
#>  2                             569                           883     1
#>  3                             932                          1233     1
#>  4                            1280                          1387     2
#>  5                            1410                          1624     2
#>  6                            1610                            NA     2
#>  7                              20                            40     3
#>  8                              80                           100     3
#>  9                              NA                           120     3
#> 10                             140                            NA     3
```

Desired output:

```r
# conceptually, I can use a 'chain' of mutate/ifelse statements
desired_df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(effective_time_from_index_end = ifelse(
    is.na(lead(effective_time_from_index_end)) |
    effective_time_from_index_end <
      lead(effective_time_from_index_start, default = 9999) - 50,
    effective_time_from_index_end,
    lead(effective_time_from_index_end)
  )) %>%
  mutate(effective_time_from_index_end = ifelse(
    is.na(lead(effective_time_from_index_end)) |
      effective_time_from_index_end <
      lead(effective_time_from_index_start, default = 9999) - 50,
    effective_time_from_index_end,
    lead(effective_time_from_index_end)
  )) %>%
  mutate(effective_time_from_index_end = ifelse(
    is.na(lead(effective_time_from_index_end)) |
      effective_time_from_index_end <
      lead(effective_time_from_index_start, default = 9999) - 50,
    effective_time_from_index_end,
    lead(effective_time_from_index_end)
  ))
desired_df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    effective_time_from_index_start effective_time_from_index_end group
#>                              <dbl>                         <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1                             373                          1233     1
#>  2                             569                          1233     1
#>  3                             932                          1233     1
#>  4                            1280                          1624     2
#>  5                            1410                          1624     2
#>  6                            1610                            NA     2
#>  7                              20                           100     3
#>  8                              80                           100     3
#>  9                              NA                           120     3
#> 10                             140                            NA     3

# This gives me the 'correct' outcome, which I can then
# filter the to get the 'bridged' time-periods
final_desired_df <- desired_df %>%
  filter(effective_time_from_index_start == min(effective_time_from_index_start, na.rm = TRUE))
final_desired_df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   effective_time_from_index_start effective_time_from_index_end group
#>                             <dbl>                         <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1                             373                          1233     1
#> 2                            1280                          1624     2
#> 3                              20                           100     3
```

But I'm sure there is a more robust and less ugly solution (tidyverse preferred, but base-r or data.table would also be very much appreciated).

Failed attempts:

```r
compare_func <- function(df, n = 6) {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (df$effective_time_from_index_end[i] > 
        df$effective_time_from_index_start[i + 1] - 60) {
      max <- df$effective_time_from_index_end[i + 1]
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
  return(max)
}
df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(effective_time_from_index_end = compare_func(.))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   effective_time_from_index_start effective_time_from_index_end group
#>                             <dbl>                         <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1                             373                           100     1
#> 2                             569                           100     1
#> 3                             932                           100     1
#> 4                            1280                           100     2
#> 5                            1410                           100     2
#> 6                              20                           100     3
#> 7                              80                           100     3
# doesn't work "by group" and need to omit NAs prior to mutate (don't want to omit NAs)


# This approach also works if you omit NAs prior to calculation,
# but I want to keep the NAs in the output
df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(effective_time_from_index_end = reduce(map(1:3, ~ifelse(
      !is.na(lead(effective_time_from_index_start, n = .x)) &
        !is.na(lead(effective_time_from_index_end, n = .x)) &
          lead(effective_time_from_index_start, n = .x) > 
            effective_time_from_index_end + 50, 
    lead(effective_time_from_index_end, n = .x),
    effective_time_from_index_end
  )), .f = max))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   effective_time_from_index_start effective_time_from_index_end group
#>                             <dbl>                         <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1                             373                          1233     1
#> 2                             569                          1233     1
#> 3                             932                          1233     1
#> 4                            1280                          1624     2
#> 5                            1410                          1624     2
#> 6                              20                           100     3
#> 7                              80                           100     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Could you clarify in row 8 - you have `effective_time_from_index_end` set to `NA` in the desired data.frame. Did you have additional logic you wanted to convert some values to `NA`? Or would it be acceptable to keep at 100?

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that's not supposed to be "NA", it's supposed to stay "100". That is apparently a bug in my 'chained mutate ifelse' approach. Sorry for the confusion. Every other value in the 'desired_df' is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but thought I would share in case it is helpful.

I might try creating subgroups based on encountering missing data or observing differences in times above 50. Then, you can change `effective_time_from_index_end` as `max` for each subgroup.

Let me know if this might work - or if not, maybe we can update the example data to show examples where things might break down.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(subgrp = cumsum(+is.na(effective_time_from_index_start) | is.na(lag(effective_time_from_index_end)) |
                           effective_time_from_index_start - lag(effective_time_from_index_end) > 50)) %>%
  group_by(subgrp, .add = T) %>%
  mutate(effective_time_from_index_end = ifelse(is.na(effective_time_from_index_end), NA, max(effective_time_from_index_end, na.rm = T)))
```

**Output**

```
   effective_time_from_index_start effective_time_from_index_end group subgrp
                             <dbl>                         <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
 1                             373                          1233     1      1
 2                             569                          1233     1      1
 3                             932                          1233     1      1
 4                            1280                          1624     2      1
 5                            1410                          1624     2      1
 6                            1610                            NA     2      1
 7                              20                           100     3      1
 8                              80                           100     3      1
 9                              NA                           120     3      2
10                             140                            NA     3      2
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I finally had a chance to test your solution and it works perfectly. Thank you for spending the time on it. Much appreciated!